# Creating a loading page for a website

Tags: angularjs, loading

I am currently working on a website and during the loading of the entire page, the page is "jumping" so that I would like to know how I can create an entire ,let's say black screen, where something is displayed during the time the page loads.

That seems quite easy but I was wondering because I have separate files for the header, the footer and the content on how to coordinate all of them, and still have a nice code.

I am working with angularJS. I read a lot about : $viewContentLoaded and also tried ng-cloak, but if any of you has an awesome solution to keep simple, it would be great :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say that one approach you can take is use some sort of templating engine for your HTML files (like [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) for example). In this way, you can keep all the code nicely separated in multiple files and using a task runner like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) you can compile your HTML files before serving the page.

The important difference here is the fact that you won't have to load all the page parts (header, footer and so on) using AJAX requests. Instead, they will already be rendered in your HTML page allowing you to create a nice loader using `ng-cloak` on your content part.